# Need a local repository for egit instead have just a remote?

Tags: eclipse, egit

Do i really need create a local repository first and than i can acess a remote repository?

I got egit from eclipse marketplace and installed.. After that i created a simple project and tried to share project with remote repository,but just can do that after i create a local repository..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Clone](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide/Remote#Cloning_remote_Repositories) the remote repository and then share the project with Team->Share project. In the "Share Project" dialog, make sure "Use or create Repository in parent folder of project" is unchecked and choose the cloned repository.

Comment: With this i dont need a local repository? Just have a remote? ty

Comment: @user1866731: With git, you always have a local repository. I highly recommend you make yourself familiar with git, the book at http://git-scm.com/book is a good start.